# Transferring from Time Machine shows "MacPorts". What is this and should I transfer it?

Tags: time-machine, macports

I am restoring from a Time Machine backup. Along with Applications, my user directory, and a few other expected things, I see an item called "MacPorts", which has a size of Zero KB.

[image]

I have no idea what this is or if I did anything over the 8 years I've had my old Mac that would have created it. What is it and should I transfer it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacPorts (a package manager similar to homebrew or Fink) creates an additional user with the name MacPorts/macports and a group with the name macports. Usually the UID(MacPorts) is the last regular user's UID+1 and the GID=UID(MacPorts).

After a normal OS X install this is 502/502 (if only one user is configured = admin) or 503/503 (if two users are present = admin and standard user).

Though the user has a non-system-user UID (>500), the account isn't visible in the Users & Groups System Preferences because it is marked as disabled. Time Machine/Migration Assistant still recognizes it.

If you don't use MacPorts anymore, you can safely ignore the account and uncheck the checkmark.